# Deleted a file manually: How can I fix Xcode project file?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm developing an iOS 4 with latest iOS SDK and XCode 4.2.

I don't know how, but I have found that one of my ViewController.xib has been moved to en.lproj folder.

I've moved this file out of this folder, and added it again to project.

But now, when I compile I get a waring saying that I en.lproj/ViewController.xib is missing from working copy.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I'd still say this.

Use something like git or svn to avoid such mistakes. The new XCode in fact gives an option for git while creating a new project.

If you are already using Code Revision Control System, just look for the commit that did this change and revert it. (I am using git language here)

Answer (score 2):

you may be having a soft link of en.lproj/ViewController.xib in project group . It will be red in color after building . You just delete them from the group.

Comment: Yes, I agree (and plus one to you)... if VansFannel sees two copies of 'ViewController.xib' in his list of files (where one is red -- which means *missing*), all he would need to do is delete that missing file reference.

Answer (score 1):

Select your ViewController.xib file in Xcode's list of files & groups along the left side of your project window and then open up file inspector and that's where you can change the path.

Here is how I do it:

[image: select and change the file path here]

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I see the correct path. The other ViewController.xib file is missing from my XCode files list.